# how get the list of selected items in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

Here I am using angular.js to show a list of people

```
  <div class="recipient" ng-repeat="person in people">
            <img src="{{person.img}}" /> person.name 
             <div class="email">person.email</div>
  </div>

$scope.people = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}];
```

The looks is like below
[image]

What I want to do is I can select multiple items and by click a OK button, I can get a list of selected items. so If I select id 1 and id 2, then I want to get return a list of [{id:1},{id:2}]

How could I implement it in angular.js

Comment: Please fill more words here for `I can get a list of selected items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess that if you're looping through a collection of people using a `ng-repeat`, you could add the `ng-click` directive on each item to toggle a property of you're object, let's say *selected*.

Then on the click on your <kbd>OK</kbd> button, you can filter all the people that have the *selected* property set to true.

Here's the code snippet of the implementation :

```
<div class="recipient" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="selectPeople(person)">
  <img src="{{person.img}}" /> person.name 
  <div class="email">person.email</div>
</div>

<button ng-click="result()">OK</button>

function demo($scope) {

  $scope.ui = {};

  $scope.people = [{
    name: 'Janis',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'Danyl',
    selected: false
  }, {
    name: 'tymeJV',
    selected: false
  }];

  $scope.selectPeople = function(people) {
    people.selected = !people.selected;
  };

  $scope.result = function() {
    $scope.ui.result = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.people, function(value) {
      if (value.selected) {
        $scope.ui.result.push(value);
      }
    });
  };

}
.recipient {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select {
  color:green;
}

.recipient:hover {
  background-color:blue;
}
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="demo">

  <div class="recipient" ng-repeat="person in people" ng-click="selectPeople(person)" ng-class="{ select: person.selected }">
    <div class="name">{{ person.name }}</div>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="result()">OK</button>

  Result :
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in ui.result">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show checked or unchecked you could just apply a filter, but you would need to toggle the filter value from `undefined` to `true` if you didn't wan't to get stuck not being able to show all again.

HTML:

```
<button ng-click="filterChecked()">Filter checked: {{ checked }}</button>
<div class="recipient" ng-repeat="person in people | filter:checked">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model="person.isChecked" />
    <img ng-src="{{person.img}}" />{{ person.name }}
    <div class="email">{{ person.email }}</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
// Apply a filter that shows either checked or all
$scope.filterChecked = function () {
    // if set to true or false it will show checked or not checked
    // you would need a reset filter button or something to get all again
    $scope.checked = ($scope.checked) ? undefined : true;
}
```

If you want to get all that have been checked and submit as form data you could simply loop through the array:

Controller:

```
// Get a list of who is checked or not
$scope.getChecked = function () {
    var peopleChkd = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = $scope.people.length; i < l; i++) {
        if ($scope.people[i].isChecked) {
            peopleChkd.push(angular.copy($scope.people[i]));
            // Remove the 'isChecked' so we don't have any DB conflicts
            delete peopleChkd[i].isChecked;
        }
    }
    // Do whatever with those checked 
    // while leaving the initial array alone
    console.log('peopleChkd', peopleChkd);
};
```

<kbd>[Check out my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/95jufwz9/5/)</kbd>

Notice that `person.isChecked` is only added in the HTML.